# One Signal Push Notification

Tags: node.js, push-notification, onesignal

How to include small icon and big icon url  while creating a push notification in node js, I know that we need to send image url while sending push notification, i need code sample in node js.. I have this code..

```
sendNotificationToSpecific =function (token,messages) {
    var sendNotification = function (data) {
        var headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Authorization": "Basic MDNlMTNjYWMTgy"
        };

        var options = {
            host: "onesignal.com",
            port: 443,
            path: "/api/v1/notifications",
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers
        };

        var https = require('https');
        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log("Response:");
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            });
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR:");
            console.log(e);
        });

        req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        req.end();
    };

    var message = {
        app_id: "awer342-d744-4787-b59a-f55c6215c491",
        contents: {"en": messages},
        include_player_ids: [token],
    };

    sendNotification(message);
};
```

Comment: What plugin you use?

Comment: i am not using any plugins

Comment: Iam trying do it this but, cant send the notification, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491033/run-one-module-after-another-is-run, can u check that?

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the docs https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-appearance you can simply extend your message object like

```
var message = {
    app_id: "xxxx",
    contents: {"en": messages},
    include_player_ids: [token],
    small_icon: "resource_name", // can not be an url
    large_icon: "http://url/ or resource_name"
}
```